# In VS Code + Python, is there a way to fold only functions (and not if/else statements)?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, folding

I'm new to Python, and I'm trying to fold my code in a way that's similar to regular Visual Studio with C#.

In VS, you can press <kbd>Ctrl+M</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl+O</kbd> to fold all methods and `#regions`, and then press <kbd>Ctrl+M</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl+P</kbd> to unfold.

VS Code has a similar feature with <kbd>Ctrl+K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl+0</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl+K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl+J</kbd>. However, this feature folds a lot of the contents of the functions, like if/else statements.

**EDIT:** Looking at the attempted answers on the duplicate question, I think the correct answer is simply that it *isn't* possible to fold Python code to only the function names.

Comment: Regarding third-party extensions, have you done your own research? What keywords have you looked for? If you tell us what you've tried, that saves us from looking where you've already looked and suggesting things that you've already tried but didn't work.

Comment: this question has been asked before, so I've closed it. unfortunately, the dup target doesn't have any correct/accurate answers (and was even wrongly closed as a duplicate). you'll need to wait for someone to give it a proper answer.

Comment: @starball The question has been asked, but as you said, it has a bunch of incorrect answers. If a person finds that thread on google like I did, they'll end up wasting time reading through a bunch of answers that don't really work.

If that's the case, then I think the correct answer is "it isn't possible to do this."

Comment: fyi, I'm planning to write a correct answer to the dup-target. As part of that, I've reached out to a maintainer about the status of a related issue ticket and am waiting on their reply.

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with #region you can still use this tag in vscode.

You could add `#region` and `#endregion` before and after the code that needs to be folder, such as:

```
# region
print("HelloWorld")

#endregion
```

[image]

You can manually click on the arrows, or use the shortcuts **ctr+8** and **ctrl+9** to collapse or expand.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question. this just adds more folding regions. the asker is looking for an efficient way to toggle folding of a specific subset of all types of folding regions.